# glVertex3f and glVertex2fx displaying different results

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, casting

I suspect it has to do with my conversion code:

```
vector3::operator float*() const
{
    // x, y, z are member floats
    float arr[3];
    arr[0] = x;
    arr[1] = y;
    arr[2] = z;
    return arr;
}
```

Then in another class I do:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3fv(origin); // wrong result
    //glVertex3f(origin.x, origin.y, origin.z); // good
    //glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // also good
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glEnd();
```

The problem is that the rectangle is stretched very far. I suspect it is because of the way I am passing the argument.

Comment: Hi @jinenofu please provide a Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `float arr[3];` is a local variable in a method. You return a pointer to local data. The data go out of scope (are lost) after the function has terminated. Read a basic C++ or C tutorial.

Comment: What is `origin`? [`glVertex3fv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) expects a pointer to 3 contiguous `GLfloat`s. Are you sure that `origin` has a type which grants this? What type does it actually have?

Comment: I assume, you want to call `glVertex` for your DIY type `vector3`? How about an "overload"? E.g. `void glVertex(const vector3 &v) { glVertex3f(v.x, v.y, v.z); }` Then, you could do e.g. `vector3 origin(1, 2, 3); glVertex(origin);`. (I made some assumptions about your code but I guess you got the idea.)

Comment: This is a C++ problem, not an OpenGL one. You're returning an address to a temporary. UB. Without seeing the sources of `vector3` it's hard to answer definitely, but the recommendation I'd give is the same - ditch your own class and just use GLM. There are apparently more ways to write a vec3 badly than to do it correctly.

Comment: @Rabbid76 There's a vast difference between the advice to "read a basic C++ tutorial" and "read a basic C tutorial".

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Not in this special case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in C/C++ legally:

> ```
> vector3::operator float*() const
> {
>     float arr[3];
>     // ...
>     return arr;
> }
> ```

It invokes undefined behavior. When `operator float*()` returns, `arr` goes out of scope and the pointer returned becomes invalid.

Consider yourself lucky, that you've got no [nasal demons](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal%20demons) ;-)

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: For one (that's OpenGL related): Don't use immediate mode (anything that makes use of glBegin/glEnd). It's outdated for over 20 years. But if you really want to go down that road and insist on using the …v versions, then put your x, y, z members at contiguous locations in your class, or use an array *there* and return a pointer to that. However this will require, that you don't use that pointer, when the class instance goes out of scope.

Comment: @jinenofu: You could also introduce a new class member function `glvertex` that internally calls glVertex.